# Shifting character in a list

Tags: python

I wanted to shift character with some specified position Ex :`Input = ['banana', 7]` here 7 is the step to move the position. `Output = utgtgt`.
It should work with any user input. User input can be lower and upper case.
numeric value is the number of position need to shift

Code:

```
input_list = ['banana', 7]
message=input_list[0]
n=input_list[1]

list1=[]
for i in message:
    ch = i
    x = chr(ord(ch)-n)
    list1.append(x)
print("".join(list1))
```

Comment: OK, but what is your question?

Comment: How do you get from `'banana` to `utgtgt`. What do you call a shift.

Comment: Try `list1 = list1.append(x)`.

Comment: @goodvibration Oh no, please don't do that! That would replace the list with `None`...

Comment: @goodvibration Wut? Why would he do that!

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `ihuhuh` BTW?

Comment: @goodvibration It *could* be, but that's apparently not the code the OP is trying to implement.

Comment: how does shifting by 7 get you to that result?

Comment: think you mean shifting by -7?

Comment: yes shifting by -7 and it should work for capital letter with any given input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should calculate the offset of a given character to the ordinal number of `'a'`, shift it by `n`, get its modulo of 26, and then get the ordinal number of the shifted character by adding the ordinal number of `'a'` back:

Change:

```
x = chr(ord(ch)-n)
```

to:

```
x = chr((ord(ch) - ord('a') - n) % 26 + ord('a'))
```

To handle uppercase letters as well, you can conditionally set the base character first:

```
base = ord('a' if ch.islower() else 'A')
x = chr((ord(ch) - base - n) % 26 + base)
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ClosedElectricEquation

Comment: Thanks its working fine but i have a problem here for capital letter like B it should convert to "U" as per code it is converting to small "o"

Comment: I've updated my answer and the demo accordingly then.

Comment: This solution only working for given input . It should work for any user input and it can contain both lower and upper case letter.

Comment: My demo has an input of `'Banana'` and it properly translates it to `'Utgtgt'` already. Is that not what you want?

Comment: its working only for 'Banana' if you give any other input like if my input is ['ytKveh' 4] its not working as expected. So it should work for any other user input.

Comment: So what would the expected output be for `['ytKveh', 4]` be? Is it not `upGrad`? If not, what is it? Don't make people guess. Clearly state the expected output given an input.

Comment: That's exactly what you get with my code. See demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/ClosedElectricEquation

Answer (score 0):

The lowercase letters only occupy codepoints 97 through 122. You have to wrap around if `ord(ch) - n` is less than 97.

```
for ch in message:
    new = ord(ch) - n
    if new < ord('a'):
        new += 26
    list1.append(chr(new))
```

Comment: This works but it is only for this particular input. Need to work for any input data.

Comment: By any, do you  mean upper or lower case? Can the input contain number, punctation, etc, which should remain unshifted?

Answer (score 0):

Building on top @blhsing answer you could get your output in one line with list comprehensions.

```py
"".join([chr((ord(ch) - ord('a') - n) % 26 + ord('a'))for ch in message])
>>> 'utgtgt'
```